# Cannot get AWS credentials programmatically. Getting "Error: connect ENETUNREACH [IP ADDRESS]"

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have copied the tutorial from the AWS website (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html). I have put the credentials file with the access key, secret token, and session id into "C:\Users\username\.aws\".

I cannot finish step 1 because when I run this file

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.getCredentials(function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err.stack);
  // credentials not loaded
  else {
    console.log("Access key:", AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId);
    console.log("Secret access key:", AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey);
  }
});
```

I get this error

> Error: connect ENETUNREACH [IP ADDRESS]
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)

Comment: location of the credentials should be `C:\Users\Username\.aws\ ` or you can set it by aws cli. Install aws cli and do `aws configure` which will create the credentials in a correct position.

Comment: @Lamanus. Yes I did that already (the question had a typo in it.